# Do I need to use a "=" in the scope to pass a function to my directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have:

```
<admin-retrieve-button ctrl="ctrl">

app.directive('adminRetrieveButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ctrl: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<button ng-click='ctrl.abc()'>Retrieve</button>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
            scope.entity = attrs["entity"];
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am unsure what is meant by binding when it comes to a function. Do I need to specify ctrl: '=' for this directive when the only thing that happens is the call to the abc() function.  Also are there any other options for the scope that would allow me to not even need to specify ctrl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing a function. You're passing the `ctrl` object and in that case you need the `'='` binding. You can bind a function to the directive scope by using the `'&'` binding.